# Error when trying to install mysql server

Tags: server, 15.10, mysql

I recently tried to install MySQL server, but I am stuck with this error:

> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

This is what I tried to do to install MySQL server:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

but after typing this command I got this error:

```
dev@webos-develop:/var/lib/dpkg/info$ sudo apt-get install mysql-
server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gnome-video-effects gyp libc-ares-dev libc-ares2 libjs-inherits libjs-jquery
  libjs-node-uuid libjs-underscore libv8-3.14-dev libv8-3.14.5 node-abbrev
  node-ansi node-ansi-color-table node-archy node-async node-block-stream
  node-combined-stream node-cookie-jar node-delayed-stream node-forever-agent
  node-form-data node-fstream node-fstream-ignore node-github-url-from-git
  node-glob node-graceful-fs node-gyp node-inherits node-ini
  node-json-stringify-safe node-lockfile node-lru-cache node-mime
  node-minimatch node-mkdirp node-mute-stream node-node-uuid node-nopt
  node-normalize-package-data node-npmlog node-once node-osenv node-qs
  node-read node-read-package-json node-request node-retry node-rimraf
  node-semver node-sha node-sigmund node-slide node-tar node-tunnel-agent
  node-underscore node-which
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.25-0ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.6.postinst: line 95: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.6; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.6 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.6
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

after i used

```
apt-cache policy mysql-server mysql-common
```

I am getting the output as

```
 mysql-server:
  Installed: 5.6.25-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.6.25-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 5.6.25-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
mysql-common:
  Installed: 10.1.16+maria-1~wily
  Candidate: 10.1.16+maria-1~wily
  Version table:
 *** 10.1.16+maria-1~wily 0
        500 http://nyc2.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.6.25-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt-cache policy mysql-server mysql-common`

Comment: @steeldriver please check my edited question

Comment: So... you appear to have a version of `mariadb` installed already - and possibly a mess of old and new repositories in your sources.list

Comment: @steeldriver      yeah thanks for this inforamtion  it is very helpful will you please give me some information about  resolving the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory`

See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.6/+bug/1455818
This problem was fixed in 5.6.27 version according to bug report.

Update:
OP says he uses Ubuntu 15.10 even though he has a tag 14.04 in his question.

While 15.10 is EOL, you should have access to 5.6.31 version of MySQL
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+package/mysql-server

The sources.list file lines you posted show xenial (16.04). I believe you upgraded the system. I hope everything is working now :)

Comment: i tried  apt-get update now and then i run the command apt-get install  mysql-server

Comment: You put a tag 14.04 but your apt-cache policy shows 'wily' which version are you using?
In your /etc/apt/sources.list make sure that `universe` is not commented out. If it was commented, uncomment it and then run apt-get update and try again to install.

Comment: Release: 15.10
                       Codename: wily and in source list it is not commented

Comment: #  # Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
#  # 'partner' repository.
#  # This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
#  # respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner

Comment: If you are using Wily, why you put a tag 14.04? Just to confuse us?
Please update your post and add the output of this command :   grep -v -e '^#' -e '^$' /etc/apt/sources.list
Also, Wily is EOL so you must upgrade it anyway. Perhaps you should upgrade to Xenial.

Comment: I am sorry to confuse you.I am new in ubuntu and i will try to upgrade.And let you know.

Comment: result of $ grep -v -e '^#' -e '^$' /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse